# Freeze mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, crud

**There is a mysql comand to freeze a table ?
In way to not insert other records in it and not modify them.**

I am a principiant , thanks to everyone.

Comment: Remove access to insert, update, or delete rows in the table.

Comment: With the Lock operation ?

Comment: . . That would go away the next time you restarted the server.

Comment: Careful - You may find tables with FKs pointing to the table in question may start erroring  and you may need to catch errors and have a process for dealing with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers on that table:

BEFORE INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name_in
BEFORE INSERT 
   ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot insert rows to this table.';
END;
```

BEFORE UPDATE

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name_up
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99998'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot update rows to this table.';
END;
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bf4b3058b476eaf0294f90f7f4f8c61)

After this it will be possible to delete rows from this table so you will need BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER if you want to stop someone from deleting rows from your table...

Comment: What is the SQLSTATE VALUE?

Comment: Hi @Matt please check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html Or you want to say VALUE is not needed ?

Comment: Hi @Matt, can you share how ? Did this answer helped ?

Comment: I have copied your code and i have done some test and changes.

Comment: Hi @Matt so then this is the correct answer ? You used triggers to manage your table ? Please accept this answer as correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
LOCK TABLES table_name [READ] ;
```

Comment: Does that lock forever or only until server reboot?

Comment: Unfortunately this would work only until server reboot.

Comment: I think it should be 'LOCK TABLES table_name [WRITE] ;' to avoid insert and update as per question :)